# java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects in Android

Tags: java, android, http, httpconnection

I am trying to download a video from a URL and getting this exception:

`java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects`

Below is my code.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
private void savePrivateExternalFile(String fileURL, String fName)
{
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = null;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try
    {
        url = new URL(fileURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty(BsharpConstant.WEB_SERVICES_COOKIES, cookie);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        File folderDir = null;
        if (clickedItemId == 0) folderDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Product") + "/Brochure");
        else folderDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Product") + "/Videos");

        File file = new File(folderDir, fName);

        if (file.exists()) file.delete();

        if (folderDir.isDirectory() || folderDir.mkdirs())
        {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); // Exception is thrown here !!
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(folderDir + "/" + fName);

            int len = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            if (clickedItemId == 1)
            {
                while ((le = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, 1024 * 50);
                while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                bufferedInputStream.close();
                Log.i("Download", "download completed in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            editSharedPreferences.putString(fName, fName);
            editSharedPreferences.commit();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), BsharpUserMessage.UNABLE_TO_CREATE_THE_FOLDER, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
01-07 14:21:36.163: W/System.err(25391): java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects
01-07 14:21:36.163: W/System.err(25391):    at l  libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:368)
01-07 14:21:36.163: W/System.err(25391):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
01-07 14:21:36.163: W/System.err(25391):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-07 14:21:36.173: W/System.err(25391):    at com.abc.xyz.ProductBrochureActivity.savePrivateExternalFile(ProductBrochureActivity.java:231)
01-07 14:21:36.173: W/System.err(25391):    at com.abc.xyz.ProductBrochureActivity.access$7(ProductBrochureActivity.java:200)
01-07 14:21:36.173: W/System.err(25391):    at com.abc.xyz.ProductBrochureActivity$2.run(ProductBrochureActivity.java:140)
01-07 14:21:36.173: W/System.err(25391):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

`

Comment: please post your LogCat here.

Comment: Apparently this is a 310 error code. The error might be located on your server.

Comment: @Manitoba what should i do for this what is the exact issue? could you please explain this. Thanks a lot for your kindness.

Comment: Could you post the script you try to call throw `fileURL` ?

Comment: Yes, what is the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: The exception suggests that the URL tries to redirect down a long chain (longer than the API is configured to allow) this can happen if the URL is set to redirect to itself.

Comment: @meiamsome what should i do for this. this is working in FireFox but not in Chrome. Why??

Comment: @user3154663 Reduce the number of redirects if possible. Does the page in question load correctly in a Private Window of FireFox? If not this would suggest a specific cookie or if specific credentials are required.

Comment: Yes @meiamsome its working on private Window of Firefox.

Comment: @user3154663 Then all this tells you is the number of redirects is less than the limit of FireFox and greater than the limit of Chrome. You need to look at the HTTP request and reduce the redirect chain.

Comment: @meiamsome how can i reduce the redirect chain??

Comment: @user3154663 That's very difficult to say without looking at the chain in question. Of course, another option is to raise the amount of redirects that the system will allow. I, however, have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @meiamsome is it right approch to download the video from url or need to use any other Media related class?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is one year old, but it comes out and has no answer so..

I had the same issue, although the link was opening in private firefox immediately.
Also, this was happening only on one device, the other 3 testing devices had no such problem.

[This answer worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23499156/1934673):

Here is the code(I corrected few typos and added StringBuilder instead of the concatenation):

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true); 
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(webLink);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
            responseBuilder.append(s);

        return responseBuilder.toString();
```