# Volley Too many redirects: 21

Tags: android, android-volley

I use volley to get data from an url, but it turns out to be failed with

```
"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects: 21"
```

when I put the url in a browser, everything is OK, It seems that volley does already handle the redirects automatically, so why?

the Volley version is:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

the android sdk:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499009/java-net-protocolexception-too-many-redirects-21-android-app

Comment: so I shouldn't use Volley in this case?