# Program runs on PC, throws ProtocolException: Too many redirects: 21 on Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I've already found a few questions about this on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499009/java-net-protocolexception-too-many-redirects-21-android-app)'s one of them), but I cannot figure out why the exception is raised when running the code on Android but not when using the JRE on my PC (Windows). I use exactly the same code and libraries.

Here's the code that throws the exception (some variables are declared prior to this scope):

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
if (cookies != null) {
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
}
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

return response.toString();
```

The exception is thrown on `conn.getResponseCode` (if removed, it's also thrown on `conn.getInputStream`). Here's the stack trace:

```
28939-28998/com.example.www W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:454)
28939-28998/com.example.www W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:348)
28939-28998/com.example.www W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:520)
28939-28998/com.example.www W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
28939-28998/com.example.www W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
```

Since I'm not sending the request to my server but simulating a browser, I cannot make changes in the server code.

Any idea why this might happen on Android while it works smoothly on my PC? I'm considering trying a different library for HTTP requests (perhaps [Basic HTTP Client](https://github.com/turbomanage/basic-http-client)), but I'm afraid it's gonna be a dull work with the same results. I also considered increasing the redirects limitation but that seems like a bad workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: @Huaying This is happening because the underlying implementations are completely different. To solve the issue, I configured the connection not to handle redirects and handled them manually instead.